# howto set up network printer (DE-agnostic solution)

Tags: printing, printer, postscript, nc

I have a network printer. I can send a postscript file to the printer using `nc`, and the printer prints it:

```
cat tiger.eps | nc 192.168.0.6 9100
```

If I want to print from my applications (ie from Thunderbird, Chromium), I can print to file (`.ps`) and then send the file with `nc`, as shown above.

However, that is quite tedious. I would like to print directly from my application.

What do I have to do, so that applications are aware that there exists a printer at `192.168.0.6:9100` and can print directly to that printer ?

What is the easiest solution? Preferably, I would like to avoid having to install CUPS.

Also, what is the purpose of the `PPD` file ? Obviously I don't need it for printing via `nc`.

I am using Debian Wheezy, and LXDE desktop environment. But I am looking for a DE-agnostic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out [LPRng](http://lprng.com/) (packaged as [`lprng`](https://tracker.debian.org/lprng) in Debian); it supports remote printing using JetDirect (which is the protocol used over port 9100), with an `/etc/printcap` file like

```
remote
   :lp=192.168.0.6%9100
```

where `remote` is the name your printer is given locally. See [the documentation](http://lprng.com/LPRng-HOWTO-Multipart/x5835.html) for details and caveats, and the Debian package's documentation too. You'll probably want to add some filtering with [`magicfilter`](https://tracker.debian.org/magicfilter) for example.

Once everything is configured, you can use `lp`, `lpq` etc. on the command-line, and the printer should also be accessible from applications. One major exception is Gtk+ 3 and KDE applications, which don't support LPR-style printing at all; if you want integrated support there you'll need to install CUPS.

PPD files allow applications to take the printer's features and characteristics into account: available paper sizes, colour capabilites, duplex capabilities, available print resolutions, minimum margins etc.

Comment: I have installed `lprng`, set up `/etc/printcap`. I can print from the command line using: `echo "hello" | lpr`. But, I still don't see the printer in my GUI applications. I am using GTK2, not GTK3.

Comment: Did you check the [Debian package's documentation](https://sources.debian.net/src/lprng/3.8.B-2/debian/README.Debian/)? The first section there explains how to configure Gtk+ 2 applications; you'll need to restart them (just the individual applications, not the whole desktop) after adding `gtk-print-backends = "file,lpr"` to either `/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` or `~/.gtkrc-2.0`.